# Updating views from UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

**Issue:**

Using the MVVM pattern, I can not refresh the views in some `sub-UserControls` that are called within an other `UserControl`.

I have a `MainWindow` which calls a UserControl, aka.`Container2`, with some components and an empty `Grid`, all of which works fine.

My `Container2` attaches in `xaml` two different sub-views (but hidden) I would like to use like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxxx"
         ...
         xmlns:Container3="clr-namespace:xxx"
         ...>
<Grid x:Name="Container2">

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource ="{Binding MyItemsSource}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Container3:Container3a_View Visibility="{Binding Visibility_Container3a, FallbackValue=Collapse}"/>
        <Container3:Container3b_View Visibility="{Binding Visibility_Container3b, FallbackValue=Collapse}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I know instead of so, someone could use, among other approaches, a Data Template Selector, but I considered going like this because some external design reasons that have nothing to do with this problem.

As an exercise for learning, both of my sub-views look the same and consist for the moment in a TabControl with two tabs each, which I load dynamically:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.Container3a_View"
    ...>
    <Grid x:Name="Container3a">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemsSource}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind of (each) sub-UserControl is like:

```
public partial class Container3a_View : UserControl
{
    public Container3a_View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Container3a.DataContext = new Container3a_ViewModel();
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel(s) like this:

```
public class Container3a_ViewModel : Container3a_Model, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Container3a_ViewModel()
    {
        // nothing here
    }

    public List<myObj> Container;
    public myObj Tab1 = new myObj("Tab1");
    public myObj Tab2 = new myObj("Tab2");

    public void InitGui()
    {
        PrintDebug("I am here");
        Container = new List<myObj>() { Tab1, Tab2 };
        RaiseEvent(Container, nameof(Container));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<myObj> TabItemsSource
    {
        get => MyConverter.GetCollection(Container);
        set => MyConverter.SetCollection(Container, value);
    }
}
```

**And the problem is:**

When I build this code, set in my Main code one of the sub-views to be visible and call its `InitGui()` method, in the grid appears the `TabControl` with no tabs and the debug sentence is printed out, what means that the sub-userControl is loaded and the Init method was called correctly (everything fine and as expected until here) but that the loading of the tabs and their text is not updated/refresh to the Gui.

If I move the loading of the tabs to inside the constructor

```
public Container3a_ViewModel()
{
    Container = new List<myObj>() { Tab1, Tab2 };
    // RaiseEvent(Container, nameof(Container)); --> not required when here
}
```

and repeat the building, this time is everything shown properly.

I can unfortunately not go with this approach, because within this sub-views there will be a lot of other new components to be developed according to certain logic.

I suspect, I am not using correctly the DataContexts or whatever, but after almost 2 days with this I cannot figure out how to make it work. Any idea will be very much thanked!

Comment: It's unclear what `RaiseEvent(Container, nameof(Container));` is supposed to be, and how it would possibly trigger a change of the TabItemsSource property. The `ObservableCollection<RObject>` collection wrapper seems pointless. The TabControl should be directly bound to an `ObservableCollection<myObj>`.

Comment: `RaiseEvent(Container, nameof(Container))` is my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, and `MyConverter.GetCollection(Container)` is a method that converts from List<T> (model) to ObservableCollection (view). These work fine, as I also use them in other programs. ´ObservableCollection<RObject>` should be `ObservableCollection<myObj>` in this transcrip, sorry for this (editing question...)

Comment: It still makes no sense at all to have a `List<myObj> Container` and an `ObservableCollection<myObj> TabItemsSource` at the same time. And it is still unclear how is the PropertyChanged event for TabItemsSource should be fired when you call `RaiseEvent(Container, nameof(Container))`?

Comment: All you seem to need is a readonly property `public ObservableCollection<myObj> TabItemsSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<myObj>()` where you add or remove elements. No PropertyChanged needed at all.

Comment: Thanks Clemens for your comments, but this is just a simplified example of a bigger program, where I need to keep this structure. As commented, it works fine for other environments other than having some UserControls called from within another UserControl...

Comment: you should rethink your MVVM structur and go Viewmodel First with DataTemplates. Its so much easier to handle ;)